# impossible to customize react-bootstrap carousel with dot

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using the carousel from `react-bootstrap` it works fine for me but the only things I can not customized are:

- arrows
- indicator lines

I just want to change the arrow color from white transparency to orange and I looking to replace the lines  by dots.

```
        <Carousel className="home-slider">
          {
            LIST.map((classitem) => 
              <Carousel.Item className="home-slider-item">
                  <img
                    className="slider-item"
                    src={classitem.classpic[0]}
                    alt="Slide"
                  />
                  <Carousel.Caption className="slider-item-content">
                    <h3>{classitem.title}</h3>
                    <p>{classitem.desc}</p>
                    <div className="slider-button">
                    <BlueButton link_href={`/classdetails?id=${classitem.id}`} text="Discover" />         
                    </div>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
              )            
          }
      </Carousel>
```

the css is :

```
.home-slider {
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

.home-slider h3{
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Fredoka One;
}

.home-slider p{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
}

.slider-item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.slider-item-content {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #ff725590;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.slider-button {
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 50px;;
}
```

This is what I have:

[image]

Any idea on how to change lines to dots and change the color of arrows?

Thanks

Comment: Bootstrap carousel is not very useful, why you don't use Owl Carousel?
It has a lots of options that you can use.

Comment: There should be a way to edit colors of arrows using css not sure about lines to dots, can you share your code on Codesandbox?

Comment: So I found out that @ꜱᴏʜᴇʟʟ had a great idea. Owl carousel will be deprecated soon but they redirect to tiny-slider and that's fixing my issue on the slider and carousel I was developing

Comment: @SOHELL pleas go ahead

Comment: @ꜱᴏʜᴇʟʟ did u have an example ? I tried using it in react and it's not properly working keep running through error

Comment: Thanks for the rep, Owl has lots of demos and examples but i don't work with react at all.
Share your error maybe you're not using it correctly and i try to help you.
I'm gonna send you codepen examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using owl carousel its the best choice, It supports almost every browser with lots of options i suggest OwlC than BS sliders.
some examples:

```
`https://codepen.io/tag/owl%20carousel/`
```

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to add the following to the css file you have imported into the project. If you run the application and build it, you can easily do it with css by looking at the tags.

```
.carousel .carousel-indicators button {
  background-color: #3c9feb;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still needs the answer I placed the whole carousel component in a div and used the is CSS to style the indicators(buttons),for the arrows I have no answer.I am using react-boostrap v2.0

```
.carouselDiv >div >div >button{
    background-color: black!important;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    height: 12px!important;
    width: 12px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the css to get it

```
.carousel-indicators li {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

.carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 12px !important;
  height: 12px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

owl carousel doesn't answer the question about React-bootstrap Carousel. To present a dynamic array of customized slides and indicators in React-bootstrap's Carousel component, there is a lot of things you need to do. Starting with the instructions at [their website](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/), I would do something like this:

```
function CustomReactCarousel(props) {
  const { items } = props;
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleSelect = (selectedIndex, e) => {
    //React-bootstrap carousel has an indexing error that causes blank slides 
    //(probably happens when you customize it). 
    //You need to account for it in this callback...
    //adjust index to 0 if selectedIndex is greater than index of last slide or 
    //it is less than zero
    //remember slide indexes are zero-based
    if (selectedIndex >= items.length || selectedIndex < 0 ){
        setIndex(0);
    } else if (selectedIndex !== index) {
        setIndex(selectedIndex);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Carousel 
        activeIndex={index} 
        onSelect={handleSelect}
        controls={true}
        nextIcon={<span aria-hidden="true" className="fas fa-chevron-right fa-3x customNextClass"/>}
        prevIcon={<span aria-hidden="true" className="fas fa-chevron-left fa-3x customPrevClass"/>}
        indicators={false}
        interval={5000}
    >
        {Items.map((item,itemIndex) => {
            return(
                <Carousel.Item className={"home-slider-item "+ item.itemSliderClass}>
                    <img
                        className={"slider-item "+ item.itemImgClass}
                        src={item.classpic[0]}
                        alt="Slide"
                    />
                    <Carousel.Caption className={"slider-item-content "+ item.itemCaptionContent}>
                        <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                        <p>{item.desc}</p>   
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
             )
        })}
        <ol className="carousel-indicators">
              {items.map((item, itemIndex) => {
                  return (
                      <li
                          key={index}
                          onClick={() => this.handleCarouselSlide(itemIndex,null)}
                          className={((itemIndex === index) ? "active" : "")+" "+item.itemIndicatorClass}/>
                  );
               })}
          </ol>
    </Carousel>
  );
}

render(<CustomReactCarousel />);
```

Notes:

1. I changed your `LIST` to `items` and made it a prop. I'm assuming it is a list of custom objects that you want to show on the Carousel.
2. I created a function as shown in the React instructions to
   accommodate the callbacks, etc.
3. Make sure you make `indicators={false}` when you add your own list
   of indicators. Otherwise, the component will make two lists.
4. Note how the "active" class has to be manually set based upon the
   select index in the custom indicator list.
5. See the comments in the handleSelect callback function about the
   array indexing error that appears when you customize React-boostrap
   Carousel. The handleSelect callback above should fix that error.

Beu is correct if you want to style the indicator buttons. Style them by referencing their `.carousel-indicators` class (whether you customize or not). Note, the `<ol className="carousel-indicators">` keeps this class name even in the customized indicator list presented above.

```
.carousel-indicators li {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

.carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 12px !important;
  height: 12px !important;
}
```

In addition to the new custom prev and next icons and their local styling performed there, you can also style their areas in css. To do that, reference the `.carousel-control-prev` and `.carousel-control-next` classes:

```
.carousel-control-prev {
    width: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.carousel-control-next {
    width: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```